# Azure DevOps API - Programmatically capture Planned vs Unplanned Work for a given Sprint

Tags: azure-devops, metrics, azure-devops-rest-api, agile

In the Velocity chart of a team (image below), it shows the planned work in light blue color. [More on this here on Microsoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/team-velocity?view=azure-devops). I think the unplanned work items can be calculated by `total work items in a given Sprint - Planned work items (light blue color)`.

[image]

**My question:** Is there a way to programmatically capture the planned work and total work items for a given Sprint? I browsed through the Azure DevOps REST API docs but I couldn't figure out a way to capture these metrics directly.

One approach would be to get a list of all User Stories for a given Iteration Path. And then for each User Story, check to see if it was added to the Iteration Path before it's start date. But I am not sure if this is feasible. It doesn't seem quite efficient.

Comment: Personally, I have never really liked the snapshotting it uses for this kind of reporting.  If you missed capturing something was really planned before the start, then the whole metric seems off and there is no way to correct these built-in reports.  Have you considered just tracking a custom field on the work item for planned vs. unplanned?

Comment: I see what you are saying. Adding a custom field might work for future work items, but I want to see some patterns in historical work items. Also, I feel people will just forget to correctly update the custom field, which can happen in large teams (absolutely understand that these fields should be accurately tracked by teams but realistically many won't)